# Linkear con twig en symfony 2

Tags: html5, symfony2, twig

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero utilizar una plantilla para mi **appweb** pero tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-renren"></i> <span class="hide-menu">Ayllus </span></a> </li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> <span class="hide-menu">Comunidades </span></a> </li>
```

Tengo enlaces de este tipo en mi barra de navegacion lateral, entiendo que el uso de *javascript:void(0)* es para no hacer nada y solo mostrar que hay un link, pero al momento de insertar el link que necesito asi:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('admin_index') }}" class="waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> <span class="hide-menu">Prueba</span></a> </li>
```

Pierdo totalmente la animación del `class="waves-effect"`, y solo aparece el nombre del link fríamente, ni *overmouse*, ni *onclick* ni nada.
Particularmente escogí este **template** por su animación de su barra de navegación.
Alguien que me pueda orientar y me diga donde está el error o de qué forma puedo agregar el *link* que necesito.
 Estoy con **symfony 2.8**, **yml**, **twig**.
Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué tan importante es que sea un elemento <a> ?
Lo que se me ocurre rápidamente es cambiar el <a> por un <div> y hacer la redirección con evento onClick.

Comment: La forma en la que lo haces es la correcta, y no se me ocurre una razón de peso para que experimentes este problema. ¿Puedes echarle un vistazo al html generador y compartirlo aquí? Quizás tras la generación hay algún elemento mal cerrado.